# Stuck at ContainerCreating

Tags: docker, kubectl

I've created my docker image which is a flask server. After I created a deployement file to create this pod on all the nodes of my cluster with the following code  :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nvf2
  labels:
        app: nvf2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
        app: nvf2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nvf2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nvf2
        image: 8e467b093efc #name of the image with docker image ls
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
```

Then I applied my file with : `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`

If I check :

```
    kubectl get pods
    NAME         READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
    nvf2-78zll   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          2m34s
    nvf2-w9xqx   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          2m34s
```

And with `kubectl describe daemonsets nvf2`

```
Name:           nvf2
Selector:       app=nvf2
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         app=nvf2
Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 2
                kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                  {"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"DaemonSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"nvf2"},"name":"nvf2","namespace":"default"},"spec...
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 2
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 2
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 2
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 0
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:  0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=nvf2
  Containers:
   nvf2:
    Image:        8e467b093efc
    Port:         4000/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From                  Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----                  -------
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  2m2s  daemonset-controller  Deleted pod: nvf2-5vvjm
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  2m2s  daemonset-controller  Deleted pod: nvf2-cfhkq
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  119s  daemonset-controller  Created pod: nvf2-w9xqx
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  119s  daemonset-controller  Created pod: nvf2-78zll
```

I don't really know where to search. If anyone can help, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I'd start with https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/. First, describe the pods themselves, not just the daemonset. `kubectl describe pod nvf2-78zll` Then grab the logs for the pods `kubectl logs nvf2-78zll`. Between the two of those, you should get a pretty good idea of what's going on. The daemonset has already done it's job of putting the pods out into the world. Further info should be pulled from the pods themselves. Check the link and follow the steps there to see what's going on.

Comment: Wrong link, sorry: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, so apparently, it just my deployment that's not working. The one proposed in example https://github.com/kubeedge/kubeedge/blob/master/build/deployment.yaml works, but not mine: https://pastebin.com/V848zWeg

Comment: I precise, that's a flask server working. I first created the docker, then tested it, and only now while deploying with Kubernetes that's a fail

Comment: @Warokam it's been already recommended to describe a pod `kubectl describe pod nvf2-78zll`  Can you add the output to your post?